# Can Firebase return only some of the attributes?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to `retrieve` some data from my `Firebase database`, but I don't want it to return all the `children` of a node.

I could achieve that, for example with `MySQL`:

```
SELECT name FROM Student;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: Show us some code that you've tried and your database structure

Comment: The Firebase Database always returns full nodes. There is no way to get a subset of the properties. But this typically is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So as Rosário said: please share the actual problem you're trying to solve and a minimal snippet of the JSON (as text, no screenshot) and code of how you're trying to solve it.